# Wildfly Data Persistence

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly

I am currently working on a Java EE project and am working with the Wildfly server.
I have a Web project and EJB project which are deployed onto the Wildfly server.
I can save a user for example, but only for as long as the server is running.
There is no data persistence between server downtimes. 
I have searched through the internet but couldn't find an answer.

My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
  <!-- If you are running in a production environment, add a managed 
     data source, this example data source is just for development and testing! -->
  <!-- The datasource is deployed as WEB-INF/kitchensink-quickstart-ds.xml, you
     can find it in the source at src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/kitchensink-quickstart-ds.xml -->
  <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
  <properties>
     <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
     <value="true"/>
  </properties>
```

If I want to persist any information, do i need to reconfigure this file?

I hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is this line

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
```

Everytime when the wildfly starts up, JPA creates a new database model with an empty database.

Adjust your code to

```
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
But it doesn't seem to work :/ i created a new EJB and then included the JPA and 
configured the persistence.xml exactly like this.

Answer (score 2):

You are using "ExampleDS" which is set up as H2 in-memory database by default. It therefore does not persist data between restarts on purpose (useful for development/testing). Go to wildfly's standalone/configuration/standalone.xml configuration file and search for "ExampleDS" in the "datasources" section. It should show:

```
<connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
```

where "mem" means in-memory. You can change "mem:test" to any write path, e.g.

```
<connection-url>jdbc:h2:~/test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
```

to use a H2 file-based database stored as "test" in your home-folder (assuming *nix).

You can also define additional databases (Postgresql, Oracle, etc) in the [datasources-section](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/DataSource+configuration).

Comment: Thank you :) I didn't know that. In the end I installed Postgresql and everything is working fine now ;)